# How to apply once context from parent in embedded component and update children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I would like to create reusable `MarkerCluster` component with leaflet map from context init it once and then provide updates on nested map components. I need to embed it not directly in `MyMap` component to perform dynamic actions from `react-router`, but when `MarkerCluster` has `shouldComponentUpdate === false` then nested markers won't update. I found that this issue might be related to [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2517), but I didn't find how to workaround this in my case. I still believe that there is better solution than just set shouldComponentUpdate to true. Could you explain difference in behaviour between my two examples? Or maybe is it a better solution to build reusable `MarkerCluster` component without context in React way?

Demo:

```js
const React = window.React;
const { Map, TileLayer, Marker, MapLayer, PropTypes } = window.ReactLeaflet;
const { markerClusterGroup } = window.L;

class MarkerCluster extends MapLayer {
  static childContextTypes = {
    layerContainer: PropTypes.layerContainer
  };
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      layerContainer: this.leafletElement
    }
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    super.componentWillMount()
    this.leafletElement = markerClusterGroup()
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate () {
    return false
  }
  render () {
    console.log("update markers cluster")
    return <div style={{display: 'none'}}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}
class MapMarkers extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
 const initialState = [
     {position: [51.5, -0.1]},
     {position: [51.51, -0.1]},
     {position: [51.49, -0.05]},
 ]
    this.state = {markers: initialState};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.addMarker.bind(this), 3000);
  }
  addMarker() {
    const lat = (Math.random() * (51.49 - 51.51) + 51.51);
    const lng = (Math.random() * (0.05 - 0.1) - 0.1);
    const marker = {position: [lat, lng]};
    this.setState({markers: this.state.markers.concat([marker])});
  }
  render() {
    console.log("update markers")
    const markers = this.state.markers.map((item, key) =>
      <Marker position={item.position} key={key} />
    );
    return <MarkerCluster>{markers}</MarkerCluster>;
  }
}
class MyMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map center={[51.50, -0.1]} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        {this.props.children}
      </Map>
    )
  }
}
class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <MyMap>
        <MapMarkers />
      </MyMap>
    )
  }
}
window.ReactDOM.render(<MainLayout />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.leaflet-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/leaflet-0.7/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/leaflet-0.7/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-leaflet@0.12.2/dist/react-leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Why example below is working and this above not?

```js
const React = window.React;
const { Map, TileLayer, Marker, MapLayer, PropTypes } = window.ReactLeaflet;
const { markerClusterGroup } = window.L;

class MarkerCluster extends MapLayer {
  static childContextTypes = {
    layerContainer: PropTypes.layerContainer
  };
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      layerContainer: this.leafletElement
    }
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    super.componentWillMount()
    this.leafletElement = markerClusterGroup()
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate () {
    return false
  }
  render () {
    console.log('update markers cluster')
    return <div style={{display: 'none'}}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}
class MapMarkers extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
 const initialState = [
     {position: [51.5, -0.1]},
     {position: [51.51, -0.1]},
     {position: [51.49, -0.05]},
 ]
    this.state = {markers: initialState};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.addMarker.bind(this), 3000);
  }
  addMarker() {
    const lat = (Math.random() * (51.49 - 51.51) + 51.51);
    const lng = (Math.random() * (0.05 - 0.1) - 0.1);
    const marker = {position: [lat, lng]};
    this.setState({markers: this.state.markers.concat([marker])});
  }
  render() {
    console.log('update markers')
    const markers = this.state.markers.map((item, key) =>
      <Marker position={item.position} key={key} />
    );
    return <div>{markers}</div>;
  }
}
class MyMap extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map center={[51.50, -0.1]} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <MarkerCluster><MapMarkers /></MarkerCluster>
      </Map>
    )
  }
}
class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
      <MyMap />
    )
  }
}
window.ReactDOM.render(<MainLayout />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.leaflet-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/leaflet-0.7/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/leaflet-0.7/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-leaflet@0.12.2/dist/react-leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: That's not what componentShouldUpdate is used for.  You've told it not to update, and now it's not updating.  If you want it to update, then don't set that hook that way.

Comment: So why second example is working?

Comment: It **is** working.  You told it not to update, and it's not updating.  If you want it to update, don't set that function to return `false`.

Comment: I found why second example is working [Known limitations](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#known-limitations) and first not. It seems that what I wanted to avoid one workaround is to update cluster component on each markers change. Does anybody knows better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you would do that.
You should understand first how react works, and how it does the reconcile process.

Take a look here, this explains the process :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

And here you can read about advanced prefomance, including a wide explanation about shouldComponentUpdate and how to use it properly:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Hopefully after youll read this you will realize why what you want is impossible.
Anyways, you should never implement shouldComponentUpdate to return false, because it will skip all of the nested components in the reconcile process.

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementation of [react-leaflet-markercluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-markercluster)

That is minimal and lightweight wrapper for Clustering markers.

Source: [src/react-leaflet-markercluster.js](https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster/blob/master/src/react-leaflet-markercluster.js)

1) Wrapper extends react-leaflet LayerGroup:

```
import {LayerGroup} from 'react-leaflet';

export default class MarkerClusterGroup extends LayerGroup {
    ...
```

2) Creating new markerClusterGroup, the group where all markers will be clustered:

```
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

let markerClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup(this.props.options);
```

3) Adding that markerClusterGroup to the map as layer, through layerContainer (layerContainer is available because MarkerClusterGroup component extending react-leaflet LayerGroup)

```
this.layerContainer.addLayer(markerClusterGroup);
```